# Find end character index of Patindex match

Tags: string, sql-server-2014, patindex

I have a PATINDEX function as appears below which returns the starting index of the string as I'd like it to but given the wild cards, I will have an unknown end of string which will be required for string manipulation. I wanted to know if it was possible to find the end of the string returned by patindex?

```
SELECT PATINDEX('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%',visitgrouptitle COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI)
```

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected output? I'm not sure this is finding what you think it should, but if it is, len(visitgrouptitle) may be what you want.

Comment: Will there be capital letters in the wildcard between digits and capital letters ? If not, CHARINDEX can look for a pattern, starting from a certain index. So you could search for capital letters, starting from the result of your PATINDEX. You would thus find the index of the first [ABC...Z] token. Add 2 and you've got the index of end of pattern